# Menu optionally displayed

Tags: magento-1.8

### it not work ! please help me!

system.xml

> ```
> <menu_category>
>                             <label>Menu Category</label>
>                             <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>                             <source_model>MW_News_Model_Config_Source_category</source_model>
>                             <sort_order>2</sort_order>
>                             <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
>                             <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
>                             <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
>                         </menu_category>
> ```

---

in Model: Category.php

> ```
> <?php
> class MW_News_Model_Config_Source_Category
> {
>    public function toOptionArray()
>    {
>        $kq = array(
>            array('value' => 'letf', 'label' => 'Left'),
>            array('value' => 'right', 'label' => 'Right'),
>            array('value' => 'disable', 'label' => 'Disable'),
>        );
>
>        return $kq;
>    }
> }
> ?>
> ```

---

template Category_right.phtml

> ```
> <?php
> $kq = (int) Mage::getStoreConfig('mw/news/menu_category');
>
>     if ($kq == 'right') {
>  <div class="">
>          <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('news') ?>" ><?php echo $this->__("News"); ?></a>
>     </div>
> <ul>
>     <?php echo $this->getMenu(); ?>
> </ul>
> }
> ```

---

.xml

> ```
> <reference name="right">
>             <block type="mw/menu" name="category_menu_right" before="-">
>                 <action method="setTemplate">
>                     <template>mw/news/category_right.phtml</template>
>                 </action>
>             </block>
>         </reference>
> ```

Comment: "it not work" is not a good error description. What do you expect from this code? What is the actual result?

Answer (score 1):

You are converting the value of your system configuration variable to an integer in this line:

```
$kq = (int) Mage::getStoreConfig('mw/news/menu_category');
```

Remove the (int) and you will get the real value (left, right, disable) of this field.